# Angular - routable modals with Root in it

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, root

I'm trying to make a modal that displays product info with a tab system inside, which is driven by rooting.

My ultimate goal is to have a root that looks like that:
'productList/productId/tab1'

which would redirect to my product list with the  product's modal open at the right tab

I am fairly new to all that is root related and I tried many solutions without success. I would like to have some advice on how I could do this.

Thanks

Comment: So only productList shows the productList? And productList/productId (with or without tab id) shows the ProductList with open modal? If so, you’d have to make routes for productList pointing to your productListComponent plus 2 routes (also pointing to the same component) like productList/:productid and productList/:productId/:tabid. Then in your comp you can check the routerparams to find out if you need to open the modal and on what tab. Does that help?

Comment: Hello, I'm pretty sure using routing for navigate inside a modal is not a good idea. Why do you need to use routing in your modal ? The tabs will work nice without routing.